# Prevent from screen recording

Tags: node.js, api, web-development-server, drm

I am working on an educational e-commercial website .. In which the user need to authenticate and then the videos on particular topics will be available.. so how can I prevent my video to be screen-recorded...

Answer (score 1):

Different OS's and applications support different mechanisms to try to tackle this - for example:

- Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 uses integrated 'Protected Media Path' for encrypted content which will stop simple screenshots working
- Website and web app developers may use a number of CCS 'tricks' to achieve a similar affect, although these can usually be workaround with standard web developer and debug tools.
- Mobile video typically uses protected memory for encrypted content which will usually give a black screen on capture.

As mentioned in comments and other answers these are all 'barriers' but they don't make it impossible to copy the content - the best example being pointing a camera at the screen a copying that way.

The idea is generally to make it hard enough compared to the value of the content so that people are not prepared to invest the time to work around your barriers.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible, for a variety of reasons:

1. There is no Web API for that.
2. Even if there was, it would be possible to reverse engineer the browser/OS to allow for screen recording.
3. Even if, for some reason, you couldn't access and modify the software running on the computer, you could connect the computer to a capture card instead of your monitor.
4. And if you also couldn't do that, you could just point a camera at the screen and start recording.

Comment: I just want to disable the screen recording like Netflix.. that's not an issue if a person point a camera and records it

Comment: But it is not possible on the Web, AFAIK.